Ansible can't see the file that is there
I have an Ansible playbook running by Jenkins job. I needed to add a conditional variable to select different existing file in automation_vars folder, but once I've done it stopped working saying there is no such file.
original working code was:
---
- name: "Check for specific vars"
  stat:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/automation_vars/{{ automation_name }}.yml"
  register: automation_vars
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: "Include specific vars"
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/automation_vars/{{ automation_name }}.yml"
  when: automation_vars.stat.exists

- name: "host alias check"
  fail:
    msg: "Unable to determine host alias list from automation_vars or environment variable"
  when: host_aliases is not defined or not ( host_aliases | length )

What it is basically doing is checking in automation_vars playbook dir for specific file supplied from automation_name variable supplied from Jenkins job. In working code output is:

TASK [build : Check for specific vars] *********************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:2
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => changed=false 
  stat:
    atime: 1734532715.1057813
    attr_flags: e
    attributes:
    - extents
[ other attributes ]
    path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/app1.yml
    pw_name: jenkins
    readable: true
[ other attrivutes ]

TASK [build : Include specific vars] ***********************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:8
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    base_ami_name_filter: bootstrap-instance-20.04-*
    builder_alias: builder
    golden_custom_vars:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    host_aliases:
    - app1
  ansible_included_var_files:
  - /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/app1.yml

TASK [build : host alias check] *************************************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:13
skipping: [localhost] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

Because in some cases I need to supply different automation_name value for those two tasks, I have added another variable called component that can be selected from Jenkins job, if it is not selected then it defaults to automation_name. I've updated my Ansible code to:
- name: "Determine the vars file to include"
  set_fact:
    automate_vars_file: >
      {{ playbook_dir }}/automation_vars/{{ 
        (component != 'default') | ternary(component, automation_name) 
      }}.yml

- name: "Debug automation_name and component"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "automation_name: {{ automation_name }}"
      - "component: {{ component }}"

- name: "Debug the automation_vars_file path"
  debug:
    var: automation_vars_file

- name: "Check for specific vars"
  stat:
    path: "{{ automation_vars_file }}"
  register: automation_vars
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: "Include specific vars"
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ automate_vars_file }}"
  when: automate_vars.stat.exists

but this time Jenkins is failing:
TASK [build : Determine the vars file to include] *******************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:13
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    automate_vars_file: |-
      /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/app2.yml

TASK [build : Debug automation_name and component] ***********************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:20
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 'automation_name: app1'
  - 'component: app2'

TASK [build : Debug the automation_vars_file path] ***************************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:26
ok: [localhost] => 
  automate_vars_file: |-
    /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/app2.yml

TASK [build : Check for specific vars] *********************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:30
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => changed=false 
  stat:
    exists: false

TASK [build : Include specific vars] ***********************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:36
skipping: [localhost] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

TASK [build : host alias check] *************************************
task path: /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/roles/build-ami/tasks/prep.yml:41
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Unable to determine host alias list from automation_vars or environment variable

I've logged in onto Jenkins agent and definitely both app1.yml and app2.yml file exists, with their content. Moreover if I set component to default in Jenkins then it also can't see the file in agent. As you can see Jenkins is passing variable value properly the problem is later with Ansible misinterpreting it, what I am doing wrong?

Looking at your Jenkins and Ansible output, there's a specific issue with path handling. The problem stems from how the set_fact module is handling the path concatenation with the ternary operator.
- name: "Set component default if not defined"
  set_fact:
    component: "{{ automation_name }}"
  when: component is not defined or component == 'default'

- name: "Set automation vars file path"
  set_fact:
    automation_vars_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/automation_vars/{{ component }}.yml"

- name: "Debug paths and variables"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "Playbook dir: {{ playbook_dir }}"
      - "Full path: {{ automation_vars_file }}"
      - "Component: {{ component }}"

- name: "Check if vars file exists"
  stat:
    path: "{{ automation_vars_file }}"
  register: automation_vars
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: "Include specific vars"
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ automation_vars_file }}"
  when: automation_vars.stat.exists

- name: "host alias check"
  fail:
    msg: "Unable to determine host alias list from automation_vars or environment variable"
  when: host_aliases is not defined or not (host_aliases | length)

Try this version and the path handling should work correctly. The debug task will help verify the paths are being constructed as expected. If you still have issues, verify the permissions and SELinux context of the files on the Jenkins agent:
ls -la /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/
ls -Z /home/jenkins/workspace/build_ami/automation_vars/

